# The relation between orders in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

G is a group and N is a normal subgroup of G.what is the relation between the order of $x$ and $x.N$?

Comment: Where does $x$ live? Is it an element of $G$?

Comment: $ord(xN)\mid ord(x)$.

Comment: Please give an example that the order of x is infinite but the order of x.N is finite

Comment: $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $N=4\mathbb{Z}$, $x=2$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $x\in G$, then the order of $xN$ divides the order of $x$.

Comment: It would be a good exercise I think for the OP to try to prove this.

Comment: I believe so, too, @Daniel.

Comment: Some care should be taken with infinite/ finiteness.